# Why do my angular2 components get re-instantiated each time I change the route?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to put together a demo app of **Angular 2** + Rx.JS 5/Next.

I noticed that my components are re-instantiated each time I switch the route.

Here is the code for the root app:

```ts
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component.ts';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

Here is the code for the root component:

```ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {FirstComponent} from './app.first-component.ts';
import {SecondComponent} from './app.second-component.ts';
import {AppService} from "./app.services.ts";


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [AppService, FirstComponent, SecondComponent],
    directives: [FirstComponent, SecondComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `<h1>An Angular 2 App</h1>
               <a [routerLink]="['First']">first-default</a> 
               <a [routerLink]="['Second']">second</a> 
               <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'First', component: FirstComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/second', name: 'Second', component: SecondComponent}
])
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Then the code for the first component (mapped to `/`):

```ts
import {Component, OnInit, NgZone} from "angular2/core";
import {AppService} from "./app.services.ts";
import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-first',
    template: `
<div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#s of someStrings">
           a string: {{ s }}
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>`
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

    zone:NgZone;

    constructor(private appService:AppService) {
        console.log('constructor', 'first');
        this.zone = new NgZone({enableLongStackTrace: false});
    }

    someStrings:string[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('ngOnInit', 'first');
        this.appService.refCounted.subscribe(
            theStrings=> {
                this.zone.run(() =>this.someStrings.push(...theStrings));
            },
            error=>console.log(error)
        );
    }
}
```

And the second component (mapped to `/second`):

```ts
import {Component, OnInit, NgZone} from "angular2/core";
import {AppService} from "./app.services.ts";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-second',
    template: `
<div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#s of someStrings">
           a string: {{ s }}
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>`
})
export class SecondComponent implements OnInit {

    zone:NgZone;

    constructor(private appService:AppService) {
        console.log('constructor', 'second');
        this.zone = new NgZone({enableLongStackTrace: false});
    }

    someStrings:string[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('ngOnInit', 'second');
        this.appService.refCounted.subscribe(
            theStrings=> {
                this.zone.run(() =>this.someStrings.push(...theStrings));
            },
            error=>console.log(error)
        );
    }
}
```

And finally the app service (slightly less relevant to this question):

```ts
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";
import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class AppService {

    constructor(){
        console.log('constructor', 'appService');
    }

    someObservable$:Observable<string[]> = Observable.create(observer => {
        const eventSource = new EventSource('/interval-sse-observable');
        eventSource.onmessage = x => observer.next(JSON.parse(x.data));
        eventSource.onerror = x => observer.error(console.log('EventSource failed'));

        return () => {
            eventSource.close();
        };
    });

    subject$ = new Subject();

    refCounted = this.someObservable$.multicast(this.subject$).refCount();

    someMethod_() {
        let someObservable$:Observable<string[]> = Observable.create(observer => {
            const eventSource = new EventSource('/interval-sse-observable');
            eventSource.onmessage = x => observer.next(JSON.parse(x.data));
            eventSource.onerror = x => observer.error(console.log('EventSource failed'));

            return () => {
                eventSource.close();
            };
        });
        return someObservable$;
    }
}
```

So in order to debug the instantiation of the `First` and `Second` components, I have added a console.log in the constructors/ngOnInit:

and I noticed that each time I change the route by clicking on the links, I get:

```ts
constructor first
ngOnInit first

constructor second
ngOnInit second
...
```

Can someone please advise whether this is expected behavior? If so how can I get Angular2 to instantiate my components only once?

Note that I have explicitly required that the `First` and `Second` components be instantiated at the root-level component by adding a `providers` array there.

P.S. Here is the github repository for this project: https://github.com/balteo/demo-angular2-rxjs/tree/WITH-ROUTER

**edit**:

I am still trying to find a solution to this problem. I am getting something wrong with the router or my components. I have pushed the app to github [here](https://github.com/balteo/demo-angular2-rxjs/commit/cf40c9a1de108667028c66c545ad0755863e647c) hoping someone can provide advice.

Comment: Did you get your solution ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**>= 2.3.0-rc.0**

A custom `RouteReuseStrategy` can be implemented to control when routed components are destroyed and recreated or reused.

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouteReuseStrategy-class.html
- https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/12/02/sticky-routes-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy.aspx
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7757

**>= 2.0.0**

`CanReuse` doesn't exist anymore in the new router. When only route parameters change while staying on the same route, the component is not recreated.

If the route is changed and navigated back to the same component the component is recreated.

**<=RC.x**

> Note that I have explicitly required that the First and Second components be instantiated at the root-level component by adding a providers array there.

Adding components to `providers: []` is mostly meaningless especially in regard to this issue.

You can implement [CanReuse](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html)

by adding

```
routerCanReuse(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) { return true; }
```

to your component, but it's quite limited for which kind of navigation the same instance is reused (if you stay on the same route and only change parameters).

If `CanReuse` doesn't fix your problem then move the data to a service, where instances are kept and bind the view of the component to the data of this service to make the component show current data.

Comment: Thanks a lot Günter, I am trying to implement the second solution (moving the data into the service). I'll accept the answer when I have managed to get it working.

Comment: I have opened another post that is related to the original post. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866215

Comment: I have placed the data into the service but due to the fact that I use an EventSource and that the components get re-instantiated upon each route change, it is still not working... See my edit.

Comment: Can you update the [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1x4WWb?p=preview) to demonstrate your issue

Comment: I have updated the plunker. Here it is: https://plnkr.co/edit/y3MBjvitr6HnR2ymTRe8

Comment: One can see in the console that the components get reinstantiated each time the links are clicked...

Comment: `routerCanReuse()` will not work in this case and is not what it is intended for. In here we are switching between two *different* component types, which will always cause the component to be re-instantiated. 'routerCanReuse()' is an optimization you can make when you have different routes that use the *same* component type (perhaps with different route parameters). In that case, re-use means to reuse the same instance for that other route.

Comment: @dtabuenc You are right of course but that's what my answer says anyway.

Comment: @balteo As mentioned in my answer `routerCanReuse` only works if the current route is updated (for example parameters change or only child route changes) but not if the route routes away from the current component. It seems to work well with the data moved to a service in your Plunker. You are still not satisfied?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: sorry for taking so long to reply and thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is absolutely expected behavior that the components will be constructed and destructed as your route changes.

Remember, components are closely associated with the DOM elements of your templates. As these dom elements are removed or changed, so must the component be destructed and a new one constructed.

There are a few exceptions to this, but not as it relates to your use-case (for example the `CanReuse` method mentioned in another answer, but that's meant for something completely different.

What `CanReuse` does, is when going from a route (let's call it `route1`) to another route  (`route2`), and both routes use the same component `MyComponent`, if you tell it that it's allowed to re-use the component, it is basically saying:

*"Since the route I'm going too uses the exact same component type as the route I'm currently on, it's ok to reuse my current component instance on the new    route" (perhaps because it's stateless for example).*

You don't say exactly what you are trying to achieve, or why it is important for your two components to be instantiated only once, but in general, components are not intended to store long-term application state (or more precisely, state that outlives the lifetime of the dom element associated with the component). These sort of things should live elsewhere (e.g. in services) and shared between components through injection (or passed in as Inputs).

Answer (score 1):

"It is absolutely expected behavior that the components will be constructed and destructed as your route changes"

The point is that components should NOT be reconstructed again and again as one navigates back and forth between two links (that are different from each other). What if you have complex graphics and state that you are modifying on one link and the object is destroyed and recreated as you arrive back to resume your work?

A framework should not dictate if the objects should be destroyed and recreated again and again. It should provide both options and in the default option, it should NOT destroy and recreate as this is the intuitive behavior. This is the behavior most UI frameworks have used over the years.