# View doesn't update after subscribe in angular2

Tags: angular

i'm new with angular 2 and i'm trying to update form input values after subscription return new data.

This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone, ChangeDetectorRef  } from '@angular/core';
import { UserInfo } from '../../lib/UserInfo'; 
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { UserInfoService } from '../../services/userinfo.service';
import { FormGroup, AbstractControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-pagina-profilo',
   templateUrl: './pagina-profilo.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./pagina-profilo.component.css'],
})
export class PaginaProfiloComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  subscription: Subscription;
  public userInfo: UserInfo;

  public name: string;
  public surname: string;

  constructor(private zone:NgZone, fb: FormBuilder, private _UserInfo: UserInfoService) {

     this.subscription = this._UserInfo.getMessage().subscribe(data => {       
     this.zone.run(() => this.updatePage(data));
 });




this.form = fb.group({
  'name': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])],
  'surname': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)])],
});
}


public updatePage(data: any)
{

this.userInfo = data

this.name = this.userInfo['name'];
this.surname = this.userInfo['surname'];

console.log("name ", this.name ); 
}

  ngOnInit() {  }
}
```

the html code to bind model with view is this:

```
<input formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" [value]="name | async">
```

the console.log inside the updatePage() function shows that the variable is updated correctly but the view html seems to not update... what's wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you remove `| async` from the HTML?

Comment: change `[value]` to `[(ngModel)]` for two-way binding...so you see the updated value

Comment: Use form style or ngModel style at once. Try to make `this.form.patchValue(this.userInfo);` in `updatePage()` method. Also, you don't need `async` it works with observables.

Comment: seems doesn't working... i think that this problem isn't only for variables inside form. Now i put a variabile in html 
    <h1>{{test}}</h1>
and the update method now change the "test" variable but seems the change doesn't happens

Comment: Just a question, is there a reason for `NgZone` here?

Comment: no, it is just a possible solution but seems it doesn't working

Comment: Hmm, I see no reason why it wouldn't work. But you can try `ChangeDetectorRef` and `detectChanges`: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef Also, like mentioned by other, `async` is not needed, and I would use `patchValue` or `setValue` instead of the `[value]` attribute :)

Comment: May be you can check [Async pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866215/angular-2-async-pipe-not-rendering-updating-observable-data-automatically) same question and answer

Comment: I have the same problem and when I remove the pipe, it works fine. Looks like the subscribe does not notify the pipe of changes. So, my solution works either if I don't use subscribe or if I don-t use the pipe. My pipe has one argument, so I updated the argument but it foes enter into the format of the pipe.